# Multiple valid answers to a question

Tags: discussion

If you have asked a question and two or more **different** valid answers have been provided, what is the best thing to do?

Should I convert the question to a community wiki, and post another answer to summarize the best answers provided?

Answer (score 5):

You should accept the solution that you applied or (if more philosophical) that you found more compelling. If they largely repeat themselves, you should simply accept the one posted earlier.

Answer (score 4):

If they are both of value vote both of them up!  Then mark one as correct based off it being more correct, the one you implemented, or whatever reason you so choose.  Either way people will be happy to get rep and recognition.

I usually comment on both correct answers telling them it helped me.  That way they know, even if I didn't mark them as correct I still found their answer useful.

Answer (score 2):

If you really can't decide, flip a coin. If the answers are of equal worth, then it really doesn't matter.

Or, what I sometimes do is choose the user with the lowest rep. Established users don't need any more points ;)